# Pester won't start up in Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, pester

I want to test a Runbook with Pester in Azure Automation.
But on the Runbook console, the pester test message are not being printed.

I've created a Runbook in Azure Automation and want to test whether those  Runbook are operating as expected.
So I've tried to use Pester to test those Runbook, but I'm not sure whether the Pester in Azure Automation Runbook are running or not.

this is the pester code that I used. a simple test:

```
Describe "Test Suite" {
    Context "Test Group"{
        It "Test Case" {
            2 | should be 2
        }
    }
}
```

below is the expected and actual result image: 
[expected value : pester process log are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lf1R.png)

[actual value : it only show the process is finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEKt7.png)

have anyone had this problem in the past?any info whether my pester code are running or not would be greatly appreciated.

bests,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at [Pester's Output Code](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/master/Functions/Output.ps1) I assume the problem is, that Pester is using Write-Host to display text.

The problem with that is, that it works just fine on local machines and I also would say it's the best way of doing it locally, but as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22430) the runbook is not considered to be a host that you can write to. This means that all the messages written to Write-Host will be ignored in the runbook's output.

So i guess as far as i understand this right, you won't get Pester tests to work or output anything in runbooks, unless you try to save it to a file with something like

```bsh
Invoke-Pester -OutputFile Test.xml -OutputFormat NUnitXml
```

and save the result to an azure storage account to take a look at it.

Anyways this doesn't seem to be the right usage of tests. Depending on your usecase you should maybe think about putting it into to any kind of build process like a build pipeline.

I hope this helps and good luck with your project.